# Bluez Profile Registration

Tags: python, bluez

I'm trying to get a bluetoothe device working in Python on Bluez5.  Currently I have the following:

```
    #set up a bluez profile to advertise device capabilities from a loaded service record
def init_bluez_profile(self):

    print("Configuring Bluez Profile")

    #setup profile options
    service_record=self.read_sdp_service_record()

    opts = {
        "ServiceRecord":service_record,
        "Role":"server",
        "RequireAuthentication":False,
        "RequireAuthorization":False,
        "Name":BTKbDevice.MY_DEV_NAME,
        "AutoConnect":True
    }

    #retrieve a proxy for the bluez profile interface
    bus = dbus.SystemBus()
    self.manager = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.bluez","/org/bluez"), "org.bluez.ProfileManager1")
    self.profile = BTKbBluezProfile(bus, BTKbDevice.PROFILE_DBUS_PATH)
    self.manager.RegisterProfile(BTKbDevice.PROFILE_DBUS_PATH, BTKbDevice.UUID, opts)
    print("Profile registered ")
```

This code executes properly and the profile code is the standard one from teh bluez test cases:

```
class BTKbBluezProfile(dbus.service.Object):
fd = -1

@dbus.service.method("org.bluez.Profile1",
                                in_signature="", out_signature="")
def Release(self):
        print("Release")
        mainloop.quit()

@dbus.service.method("org.bluez.Profile1",
                                in_signature="", out_signature="")
def Cancel(self):
        print("Cancel")

@dbus.service.method("org.bluez.Profile1", in_signature="oha{sv}", out_signature="")
def NewConnection(self, path, fd, properties):
        self.fd = fd.take()
        print("NewConnection(%s, %d)" % (path, self.fd))
        for key in properties.keys():
                print ('key ' + key + ' value ' + properties[key])
                if key == "Version" or key == "Features":
                        print("  %s = 0x%04x" % (key, properties[key]))
                else:
                        print("  %s = %s" % (key, properties[key]))



@dbus.service.method("org.bluez.Profile1", in_signature="o", out_signature="")
def RequestDisconnection(self, path):
        print("RequestDisconnection(%s)" % (path))

        if (self.fd > 0):
                os.close(self.fd)
                self.fd = -1

def __init__(self, bus, path):
        dbus.service.Object.__init__(self, bus, path)
```

However when I get connections/disconnections nothing works.  I've tried playing around with the various options but I just can't get anything to register.  The documentation is light and there seems to be little debugging info I can get on the dbus communication.  Has anybody succeeded in regsitering a profile and/or obtaining more debugging information on the bluez interaction?

Thanks.

Comment: If you already in Linux environment, try running `bluetoothctl show <Adapter MAC>` and check whether the UUID appears in bluetoothd level. You can also monitor all the dbus communication using `dbus-monitor --system` and share that info here.

Comment: Thanks; I'll get onto that first thing Monday.  For the sake of my family I left the RPi0W on my desk at work!

Comment: The reply from the d0bus on service registration is:

Comment: signal time=1538418064.349571 sender=:1.21 -> destination=(null destination) serial=10 path=/org/bluez/hci0; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties; member=PropertiesChanged
   string "org.bluez.Adapter1"
   array [
      dict entry(
         string "UUIDs"
         variant             array [
               string "00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
               string "00001124-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
               string "00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
               string "00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
            ]
      )
   ]
   array [
   ]

Comment: so that is working

Comment: on connection we get on the dbus

Comment: signal time=1538418299.333476 sender=:1.0 -> destination=(null destination) serial=321 path=/org/freedesktop/systemd1; interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager; member=UnitNew
   string "sys-devices-platform-soc-20201000.serial-tty-ttyAMA0-hci0-hci0:11.device"
   object path "/org/freedesktop/systemd1/unit/sys_2ddevices_2dplatform_2dsoc_2d20201000_2eserial_2dtty_2dttyAMA0_2dhci0_2dhci0_3a11_2edevice"
signal time=1538418299.336381 sender=:1.0 -> destination=(null destination) serial=322 path=/org/freedesktop/systemd1; interface=org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager; member=UnitNew

Comment: and crucially
signal time=1538418299.364910 sender=:1.21 -> destination=(null destination) serial=27 path=/org/bluez/hci0/dev_C8_FF_28_79_05_D4; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties; member=PropertiesChanged
   string "org.bluez.Device1"
   array [
      dict entry(
         string "Connected"
         variant             boolean true
      )
   ]
   array [
   ]

Comment: this makes me think that the message is going out on the dbus but my dbus profile is not catching the connection.  Looking at it one thing that I'm not sure of is that the bluez example references an interfae called org.bluez.Profile1 but this is not in the output from dbus.  I'm wondering in the output what is the interface - is it 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties' I wonder?

Comment: From the list of uuids I understand that all the uuids are common ones as in https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/lib/uuid.h. What is the UUID which your are registering with bluez?

Comment: It is 00001124-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb which is the one that references a HID

Comment: Ok. one more thing. After the device is connected, `bluetoothctl info <Devive MAC>` run this command share the output.

Comment: running that command drops me into a bluetooth terminal prompt [bluetooth]#; then when I try to execute info B8:27:EB:14:FB:B1 (that is the device mac) then I get No default controller available.  Note that I am running on the device itself which is a RPi0W.

Comment: Ok, am not getting it. I see HID UUID is supported in adapter end. I also wanted you to cross check whether the same is supported in device end also. If your are running `bluetoothctl` in device CLI, then try using `show` option

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181105/discussion-between-neil-benn-and-parthiban).

Answer (score 3):

This is a successful HID Keyboard implementation that is documented at:
https://gist.github.com/ukBaz/a47e71e7b87fbc851b27cde7d1c0fcf0

```py
"""
Bluetooth HID keyboard emulator DBUS Service
Original idea taken from:
http://yetanotherpointlesstechblog.blogspot.com/2016/04/emulating-bluetooth-keyboard-with.html
Moved to Python 3 and tested with BlueZ 5.43
Updates documented at:
https://gist.github.com/ukBaz/a47e71e7b87fbc851b27cde7d1c0fcf0
"""
import os
import sys
import dbus
import dbus.service
import socket


from gi.repository import GLib
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop


class HumanInterfaceDeviceProfile(dbus.service.Object):
    """
    BlueZ D-Bus Profile for HID
    """
    fd = -1

    @dbus.service.method('org.bluez.Profile1',
                         in_signature='', out_signature='')
    def Release(self):
            print('Release')
            mainloop.quit()

    @dbus.service.method('org.bluez.Profile1',
                         in_signature='oha{sv}', out_signature='')
    def NewConnection(self, path, fd, properties):
            self.fd = fd.take()
            print('NewConnection({}, {})'.format(path, self.fd))
            for key in properties.keys():
                    if key == 'Version' or key == 'Features':
                            print('  {} = 0x{:04x}'.format(key,
                                                           properties[key]))
                    else:
                            print('  {} = {}'.format(key, properties[key]))

    @dbus.service.method('org.bluez.Profile1',
                         in_signature='o', out_signature='')
    def RequestDisconnection(self, path):
            print('RequestDisconnection {}'.format(path))

            if self.fd > 0:
                    os.close(self.fd)
                    self.fd = -1


class BTKbDevice:
    """
    create a bluetooth device to emulate a HID keyboard
    """
    MY_DEV_NAME = 'BT_HID_Keyboard'
    # Service port - must match port configured in SDP record
    P_CTRL = 17
    # Service port - must match port configured in SDP record#Interrrupt port
    P_INTR = 19
    # BlueZ dbus
    PROFILE_DBUS_PATH = '/bluez/yaptb/btkb_profile'
    ADAPTER_IFACE = 'org.bluez.Adapter1'
    DEVICE_INTERFACE = 'org.bluez.Device1'
    DBUS_PROP_IFACE = 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties'
    DBUS_OM_IFACE = 'org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager'

    # file path of the sdp record to laod
    install_dir  = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    SDP_RECORD_PATH = os.path.join(install_dir,
                                   'sdp_record.xml')
    # UUID for HID service (1124)
    # https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/service-discovery
    UUID = '00001124-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'

    def __init__(self, hci=0):
        self.scontrol = None
        self.ccontrol = None  # Socket object for control
        self.sinterrupt = None
        self.cinterrupt = None  # Socket object for interrupt
        self.dev_path = '/org/bluez/hci{}'.format(hci)
        print('Setting up BT device')
        self.bus = dbus.SystemBus()
        self.adapter_methods = dbus.Interface(
            self.bus.get_object('org.bluez',
                                self.dev_path),
            self.ADAPTER_IFACE)
        self.adapter_property = dbus.Interface(
            self.bus.get_object('org.bluez',
                                self.dev_path),
            self.DBUS_PROP_IFACE)

        self.bus.add_signal_receiver(self.interfaces_added,
                                     dbus_interface=self.DBUS_OM_IFACE,
                                     signal_name='InterfacesAdded')

        self.bus.add_signal_receiver(self._properties_changed,
                                     dbus_interface=self.DBUS_PROP_IFACE,
                                     signal_name='PropertiesChanged',
                                     arg0=self.DEVICE_INTERFACE,
                                     path_keyword='path')

        print('Configuring for name {}'.format(BTKbDevice.MY_DEV_NAME))

        self.config_hid_profile()

        # set the Bluetooth device configuration
        self.alias = BTKbDevice.MY_DEV_NAME
        self.discoverabletimeout = 0
        self.discoverable = True

    def interfaces_added(self):
        pass

    def _properties_changed(self, interface, changed, invalidated, path):
        if self.on_disconnect is not None:
            if 'Connected' in changed:
                if not changed['Connected']:
                    self.on_disconnect()

    def on_disconnect(self):
        print('The client has been disconnect')
        self.listen()

    @property
    def address(self):
        """Return the adapter MAC address."""
        return self.adapter_property.Get(self.ADAPTER_IFACE,
                                         'Address')

    @property
    def powered(self):
        """
        power state of the Adapter.
        """
        return self.adapter_property.Get(self.ADAPTER_IFACE, 'Powered')

    @powered.setter
    def powered(self, new_state):
        self.adapter_property.Set(self.ADAPTER_IFACE, 'Powered', new_state)

    @property
    def alias(self):
        return self.adapter_property.Get(self.ADAPTER_IFACE,
                                         'Alias')

    @alias.setter
    def alias(self, new_alias):
        self.adapter_property.Set(self.ADAPTER_IFACE,
                                  'Alias',
                                  new_alias)

    @property
    def discoverabletimeout(self):
        """Discoverable timeout of the Adapter."""
        return self.adapter_props.Get(self.ADAPTER_IFACE,
                                      'DiscoverableTimeout')

    @discoverabletimeout.setter
    def discoverabletimeout(self, new_timeout):
        self.adapter_property.Set(self.ADAPTER_IFACE,
                                  'DiscoverableTimeout',
                                  dbus.UInt32(new_timeout))

    @property
    def discoverable(self):
        """Discoverable state of the Adapter."""
        return self.adapter_props.Get(
            self.ADAPTER_INTERFACE, 'Discoverable')

    @discoverable.setter
    def discoverable(self, new_state):
        self.adapter_property.Set(self.ADAPTER_IFACE,
                                  'Discoverable',
                                  new_state)

    def config_hid_profile(self):
        """
        Setup and register HID Profile
        """

        print('Configuring Bluez Profile')
        service_record = self.read_sdp_service_record()

        opts = {
            'Role': 'server',
            'RequireAuthentication': False,
            'RequireAuthorization': False,
            'AutoConnect': True,
            'ServiceRecord': service_record,
        }

        manager = dbus.Interface(self.bus.get_object('org.bluez',
                                                     '/org/bluez'),
                                 'org.bluez.ProfileManager1')

        HumanInterfaceDeviceProfile(self.bus,
                                    BTKbDevice.PROFILE_DBUS_PATH)

        manager.RegisterProfile(BTKbDevice.PROFILE_DBUS_PATH,
                                BTKbDevice.UUID,
                                opts)

        print('Profile registered ')

    @staticmethod
    def read_sdp_service_record():
        """
        Read and return SDP record from a file
        :return: (string) SDP record
        """
        print('Reading service record')
        try:
            fh = open(BTKbDevice.SDP_RECORD_PATH, 'r')
        except OSError:
            sys.exit('Could not open the sdp record. Exiting...')

        return fh.read()   

    def listen(self):
        """
        Listen for connections coming from HID client
        """

        print('Waiting for connections')
        self.scontrol = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH,
                                      socket.SOCK_SEQPACKET,
                                      socket.BTPROTO_L2CAP)
        self.scontrol.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.sinterrupt = socket.socket(socket.AF_BLUETOOTH,
                                        socket.SOCK_SEQPACKET,
                                        socket.BTPROTO_L2CAP)
        self.sinterrupt.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.scontrol.bind((self.address, self.P_CTRL))
        self.sinterrupt.bind((self.address, self.P_INTR))

        # Start listening on the server sockets
        self.scontrol.listen(1)  # Limit of 1 connection
        self.sinterrupt.listen(1)

        self.ccontrol, cinfo = self.scontrol.accept()
        print('{} connected on the control socket'.format(cinfo[0]))

        self.cinterrupt, cinfo = self.sinterrupt.accept()
        print('{} connected on the interrupt channel'.format(cinfo[0]))

    def send(self, msg):
        """
        Send HID message
        :param msg: (bytes) HID packet to send
        """
        self.cinterrupt.send(bytes(bytearray(msg)))


class BTKbService(dbus.service.Object):
    """
    Setup of a D-Bus service to recieve HID messages from other
    processes.
    Send the recieved HID messages to the Bluetooth HID server to send
    """
    def __init__(self):
        print('Setting up service')

        bus_name = dbus.service.BusName('org.yaptb.btkbservice',
                                        bus=dbus.SystemBus())
        dbus.service.Object.__init__(self, bus_name, '/org/yaptb/btkbservice')

        # create and setup our device
        self.device = BTKbDevice()

        # start listening for socket connections
        self.device.listen()

    @dbus.service.method('org.yaptb.btkbservice',
                         in_signature='ay')
    def send_keys(self, cmd):
        self.device.send(cmd)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # The sockets require root permission
    if not os.geteuid() == 0:
        sys.exit('Only root can run this script')

    DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
    myservice = BTKbService()
    mainloop = GLib.MainLoop()
    mainloop.run()
```

'sdp_record.xml'

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<record>
    <attribute id="0x0001">
        <sequence>
            <uuid value="0x1124" />
        </sequence>
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="0x0004">
        <sequence>
            <sequence>
                <uuid value="0x0100" />
                <uint16 value="0x0011" />
            </sequence>
            <sequence>
                <uuid value="0x0011" />
            </sequence>
        </sequence>
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="0x0005">
        <sequence>
            <uuid value="0x1002" />
        </sequence>
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="0x0006">
        <sequence>
            <uint16 value="0x656e" />
            <uint16 value="0x006a" />
            <uint16 value="0x0100" />
        </sequence>
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="0x0009">
        <sequence>
            <sequence>
                <uuid value="0x1124" />
                <uint16 value="0x0100" />
            </sequence>
        </sequence>
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="0x000d">
        <sequence>
            <sequence>
                <sequence>
                    <uuid value="0x0100" />
                    <uint16 value="0x0013" />
                </sequence>
                <sequence>
                    <uuid value="0x0011" />
                </sequence>
            </sequence>
        </sequence>
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="0x0100">
        <text value="Raspberry Pi Virtual Keyboard" />
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="0x0101">
        <text value="USB > BT Keyboard" />
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="0x0102">
        <text value="Raspberry Pi" />
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="0x0200">
        <uint16 value="0x0100" />
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="0x0201">
        <uint16 value="0x0111" />
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="0x0202">
        <uint8 value="0x40" />
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="0x0203">
        <uint8 value="0x00" />
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="0x0204">
        <boolean value="false" />
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="0x0205">
        <boolean value="false" />
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="0x0206">
        <sequence>
            <sequence>
                <uint8 value="0x22" />
                <text encoding="hex" value="05010906a101850175019508050719e029e715002501810295017508810395057501050819012905910295017503910395067508150026ff000507190029ff8100c0050c0901a1018503150025017501950b0a23020a21020ab10109b809b609cd09b509e209ea09e9093081029501750d8103c0" />
            </sequence>
        </sequence>
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="0x0207">
        <sequence>
            <sequence>
                <uint16 value="0x0409" />
                <uint16 value="0x0100" />
            </sequence>
        </sequence>
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="0x020b">
        <uint16 value="0x0100" />
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="0x020c">
        <uint16 value="0x0c80" />
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="0x020d">
        <boolean value="true" />
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="0x020e">
        <boolean value="false" />
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="0x020f">
        <uint16 value="0x0640" />
    </attribute>
    <attribute id="0x0210">
        <uint16 value="0x0320" />
    </attribute>
</record>
```